# What does x=x[class_id] do when used on NumPy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, shuffle

I am learning Python and solving a machine learning problem.

```
class_ids=np.arange(self.x.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(class_ids)
self.x=self.x[class_ids]
```

This is a shuffle function in NumPy but I can't understand what `self.x=self.x[class_ids]` means. because I think it gives the value of the array to a variable.

Comment: Print `self.x` before and after the assignment statement.  What does it do?

Comment: [Integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)

Comment: What is `self.x`? Can you show its initialization?

Comment: The intent of the code seems to be to shuffle `self.x` in which case I would assume `np.random.shuffle(self.x)` would suffice

Comment: the code above is the basic step of loading omniglot Dataset and try to shuffle it for training or test and self.x is the data of those pictures which are shaped like  self.x = np.reshape(self.x, newshape=(1622, 20, 28, 28, 1))  @PaulRooney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `self.x` is a numpy array:

`class_ids` is a 1-d numpy array that is being used as an [integer array index](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) in the expression: `x[class_ids]`.  Because the previous line shuffled `class_ids`, `x[class_ids]` evaluates to `self.x` shuffled by rows.
The assignment `self.x=self.x[class_ids]` assigns the shuffled array to `self.x`

Answer (score 1):

It's a very complicated way to shuffle the first dimension of your `self.x`. For example:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]])
>>> x
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4],
       [5, 5]])
```

Then using the mentioned approach

```
>>> class_ids=np.arange(x.shape[0])  # create an array [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> np.random.shuffle(class_ids)     # shuffle the array
>>> x[class_ids]                     # use integer array indexing to shuffle x
array([[5, 5],
       [3, 3],
       [1, 1],
       [4, 4],
       [2, 2]])
```

Note that the same could be achieved just by using [`np.random.shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) because the docstring explicitly mentions:

> This function only shuffles the array along the first axis of a multi-dimensional array. The order of sub-arrays is changed but their contents remains the same.

```
>>> np.random.shuffle(x)
>>> x
array([[5, 5],
       [3, 3],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [4, 4]])
```

or by using [`np.random.permutation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html#numpy.random.permutation):

```
>>> class_ids = np.random.permutation(x.shape[0])  # shuffle the first dimensions indices
>>> x[class_ids]
array([[2, 2],
       [4, 4],
       [3, 3],
       [5, 5],
       [1, 1]])
```